Why is PyDub segfaulting?
I am running a simple script to record audio in pydub and play it back. It is playing it back, but after the playback, it is throwing a segementation fault at me, and i have no idea why.
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
import wavio

def record_audio(duration=5, sample_rate=44100):
    print("Recording...")
    audio = sd.rec(int(duration * sample_rate), samplerate=sample_rate, channels=2, dtype='int16')
    sd.wait()
    
    # Save the recorded audio as a WAV file
    wavio.write("recorded.wav", audio, sample_rate, sampwidth=2)
    print("Recording saved as recorded.wav")

def play_audio(file_path):
    print("Playing back...")
    audio = AudioSegment.from_wav(file_path)
    play(audio)
    print("Playback finished")

# Record and playback
record_audio()
play_audio("recorded.wav")


Here is the code
python audio.py
Recording...
Recording saved as recorded.wav
Playing back...
[1]    25425 segmentation fault (core dumped)  python audio.py

Here is the output. Any solutions?
I am on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
OS: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS x86_64 
Host: Vostro 3590 
Kernel: 6.8.0-1012-oem 
Uptime: 1 hour, 43 mins 
Packages: 3095 (dpkg), 61 (brew), 6 (flatpak), 40 (snap) 
Shell: zsh 5.9 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: GNOME 46.0 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Yaru-blue-dark [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Yaru-blue [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: tilix 
CPU: Intel i5-10210U (8) @ 4.200GHz 
GPU: Intel CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics] 
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon R5 M230 / R7 M260DX / Radeon 52      Memory: 5288MiB / 7662MiB 

I tried other modules, but simpleaudio is also segfaulting, and pygame seems like avoiding the problem for me. I honestly did not try anything because I have no idea whats failing. ChatGPT is useless in this problem for me.

Even if due to a user error, I think a segfault deserves a bug report. You should report this to pydub devs.
